# Rancher does not persist environment variables when upgrading a service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline, devops, rancher

I have the following issue. I use rancher-compose to upgrade my services. I set in the UI an environment variable and then I run the compose command from the terminal. After the upgrade the environment variable I set previously in the UI is not set anymore.

The rancher-compose command I use is:

```
rancher-compose -p [my_stack_name] --url ${RANCHER_ENDPOINT} --access-key ${ACCESS_KEY} --secret-key ${SECRET_KEY} up -d --pull --upgrade --confirm-upgrade
```

Any thoughts ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade makes the service match the definition in the compose file you provide.  If you change things in the UI but don't change your compose file, they're going to be losr.